# ngOnChanges Angular doesn't work on two way data binding [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular

ngOnChanges doesn't fire when user property change with ngModel, it's strange for me because i was worked with vue js and computed methods and i guess it's the same here.

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnChanges {
  title = 'app';
  user = '';

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    console.log('user changed !');
  }
}
```

**view**

```
<input type="text"
       name="user"
       id="user"
       [(ngModel)]='user'>


<p>{{user}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO `ngOnChanges` only runs when the Input property changes come from a template binding for example

```
<component [inputBinding]="someValue">
```

and won't work with two-way data binding like you are doing above.

Comment: thanks for response, What i need if i need something like computed method to track properties changes

Comment: In this case, you have to tell angular to run change detection forcefully. you can run manually too.

Comment: i can use ngDoCheck() for this it's pretty fine i guess for this situation.

Comment: yes `ngDoCheck` will work, I was thinking you have to use `ngOnChanges` only.

Answer (score 0):

ngOnChanges is only called when the input from the parent component is changed. According to your requirement, you need to implement a change event listener on your input. For Eg.

```
<input type="text"
       name="user"
       id="user"
       [(ngModel)]='user'
       (input)="inputChange(event)">
```

here inputChange is the function that will be called each time user inputs something.
For more details you can see the official docs of Angular for events on input Elements - https://angular.io/guide/event-binding

Answer (score 0):

`[(ngModel)]` only works when you import `FormsModule` in your module. I think, you have not imported it & trying to access it that's why user value is not changing in HTML templete on input change.

`ngOnChanges` is a life cycle hook, called every time when an input property changes for a component or directive. I will not be called on `[(ngModel)]`, if you want to trigger `ngModel` change, you can use `ngModelChange` like this on input element:

```
<input type="text" name="user" id="user" [(ngModel)]='user' (ngModelChange)="onInputChange($event)" />
```

If you want to print user value in HTML template, you can directly write `<p>{{user}}</p>` & it will automatically change when you type. in this case you don't need to use `ngModelChange`.

For more information, please read the documentation https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges